# Is it possible to generate a unique id for new models in Backbone collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a Backbone collection from serer with attributes `id` and `name`.

I get new name from input.

```
var a = $('#newFoodtype').val();
```

And create new model and adding to collection;

```
var b = new app.Foodtype({ "name" :a });
this.collection.add(b);
```

The new model doesn't have an `id` attribute. I know all model have a `id`.

**How to generate a unique id and set this to new models.**

I will delete some models in collection, therefore `collection.length` is good idea. I will send this to the server. One solution is to send only the `"name"` and generate the `"id"` on the server during the insert to the DB.

Is it possible to generate this from the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One solution is to send only the `"name"` and generate the `"id"` on the server during the insert to the DB.

**The `id`, if saved in a database, should be handled by the database.** Never try to increment the last id or use the collection length as a unique identifier.

## Temporary client id: `cid`

Backbone gives model and views a [`cid` property](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-cid) which is a "client id". It is unique only to that client instance and won't be unique after a refresh. It serves to identify models before they are saved and given their final id.

```
var newModel = Backbone.Model({ name: "new model" });
console.log(newModel.cid); // e.g.: "c123"
```

## Generating GUID

If it's not an id for the database, but only a unique identifier for business logic, you could generate a GUID with a low chance of collision.

See [Create GUID / UUID in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/105034/1218980)